# Does the series $\sum\ln(1+\frac{1}{n\ln(n)})$ Converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As the title states I wanna prove this series converges or not however I noted that if we fan transform $\ln(1+\frac{1}{n\ln(n)})$ into some known limit identity and use Comparison test I would be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the series :
$$
\sum b_{n}=\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}
$$

Applying the limit comparison test yields :
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}\right)}{\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}}
$$
Let $\displaystyle u=\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$, then :
$$
\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}=1
$$
Since the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ diverges by the integral test, it follows that your main series diverges by the limit comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

For large $n$:

$\log (1+\dfrac{1}{n\log n})\sim$
$\dfrac{1}{n\log n}.$

$\displaystyle{\sum }\dfrac{1}{n\log n}$ diverges (Cauchy condensation test).